# payment() invoked twice after express checkout button is clicked. Lightbox keep spinning

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I am trying to integrate the `express-checkout` API with `node.js` and `express`. It's my first time using PayPal's API and I am having trouble getting the lightbox to stop spinning and allowing the user to approve and authorize the payment. When the user clicks the checkout button, the `payment` method is invoked twice (2 payments are created with 2 different ids with a time difference of about 2 mins) and the lightbox pops up but keeps spinning and doesn't prompt the user to do anything. I appreciate any help on this.

My client-side code:

```
      <div id="paypal-button"></div>

      <script>
        paypal.Button.render({
          env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

          commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

          style: {
            color: 'gold',
            size: 'small'
          },

          payment: function() {
            /* Make a call to the server to set up the payment */
            return paypal.request.post("http://localhost:3000/paypal/create-payment")
                .then(function(res) { 
                    return res.id; 
                })
            },

          onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            /* 
             * Execute the payment here 
             */

            return paypal.request.post("http://localhost:3000/paypal/execute-payment",
                {
            paymentID: data.paymentID,
            payerID:   data.payerID
            }).then(function(res) {

            // The payment is complete!
            // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
            window.alert("PAYMENT COMPLETE!");
            });
          },

          onCancel: function(data, actions) {
            /* 
             * Buyer cancelled the payment 
             */
            console.log("BUYER CANCELLED!");
          },

          onError: function(err) {
            /* 
             * An error occurred during the transaction 
             */
            console.log(err);
          }
        }, '#paypal-button');
      </script>
```

My server-side code:

```
// CREATE PAYMENT ROUTE
app.post("/paypal/create-payment", function(req, res){
// CREATE JSON REQUEST 
var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
  "redirect_urls":
  {
    "return_url": "https://localhost:3000/success",
    "cancel_url": "https://localhost:3000/cancel"
  },
  "payer":
  {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
  {
    "amount":
    {
      "total": "",
      "currency": "USD",
      "details":{
        "subtotal": "",
        "shipping": "0.00",
        "tax": "0.00",
        "shipping_discount": "0.00"
      }
    },
    "item_list":
    {
      "items": []
    },
    "description": "Test shopping cart transaction."
  }]
};

// Change the "total", "subtotal", and "items" array in the json request
create_payment_json["transactions"][0]["amount"]["total"] = cart.totalPrice.toString();
create_payment_json["transactions"][0]["amount"]["details"]["subtotal"] = cart.totalPrice.toString();

// Dummy variable for less typing 
var itemsArray = create_payment_json["transactions"][0]["item_list"]["items"];

// 1) Access each puppy in the cart
// 2) Create an object with the following properties:
//          quantity, name, price, currency, description, and tax
// 3) push that object into itemsArray
 cart["puppies"].forEach(function(puppy){
    var dummy = {
        "quantity" : "1",
        "name" : puppy.name,
        "price" : puppy.price.toString(),
        "currency" : "USD",
        "description" : puppy.description,
        "tax" : "0"
    };
    itemsArray.push(dummy);
 });

// Send a Create Payment request to the Payments API
    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(payment);
            console.log("==============");
        }
    });
});

// EXECUTE PAYMENT ROUTE 
app.post("/paypal/execute-payment", function(req, res){
var payerId = { payer_id: req.query.PayerID };
var paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

console.log("Payer ID: " + payerId);
console.log("Paymend ID: " + paymentId);

    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, payerId, function(error, payment){
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            if(payment.state === "approved"){
                console.log(payment);
                res.send("SUCCESS");
            } else {
                console.log("payment not successful");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

The `console.log(payment)` in the `paypal.payment.create` method is run twice. That's how I know that the `payment` method is invoked twice. I don't know how to solve this. Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Update: changed `return res.paymentId` into `return res.id`, but no luck.

Comment: There is two `console.log(payment);` too... One in `paypal.payment.create()` and on in `paypal.payment.execute()`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The `console.log("==============");` line in `paypal.payment.create()` is what I use to differentiate between the two logs. Both logged payments have ==== afterwards.

Comment: okay... I just said you have it twice in you code, so that is pretty normal is is shown twice. But what you are saying is the one in `paypal.payment.create()` runs twice... And then the one in `paypal.payment.execute()`, which make three times total... right? (I may be lost too...)

Comment: oh no, the `execute route` is never fired. After both payments (from `paypal.payment.create()` are logged, the lightbox keeps spinning for a long time and then it closes with no errors shown in the console and nothing happens.

Comment: On this line on client-side: `payment: function() {`, isn't there any missing args? Like data and actions ?

Comment: I am not sure. I am following the sample code in this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/server-side-REST-integration/ Other links have those two arguments. I've tried adding them but still no luck!

Comment: Ok... I just had this idea. Is it possible that you call the checkout.js script twice? Like in the `<head>` and in the `<bottom>` or something... Else, I have no other clue.

Comment: No I am not. It's only in the `<head>`